Error on mountig Windows 11 share on Ubuntu Server (or Desktop) 24.04
I am trying to mount a Windows 11 share on Ubuntu Linux, version 24.04, both desktop and server edition, with no success.
I tried the following command:
mount -t cifs -o user=guest,password= //host/share mountingPoint
I got this error message:
mount error(95): Operation not supported
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)

And from dmesg:
[349174.481029] CIFS: Attempting to mount //host/share
[349174.487746] CIFS: VFS: parse_reparse_point: unhandled reparse tag: 0x9000701a
[349174.487775] CIFS: VFS: cifs_read_super: get root inode failed

The exact same command works perfectly on Ubuntu 22.04 desktop.
What am I missing? I realize that these versions are very new and maybe buggy, but peharps I missing something obvious.

Please don't post the same questions to multiple sites, as you did with this one and https://askubuntu.com/q/1515972/636008

Yep!
Make sure that you have the necessary packages installed.
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cifs-utils

And that the kernel module for CIFS is loaded:
sudo modprobe cifs

Sometimes specific options are required to properly mount the share. Specify the version of the SMB protocol:
sudo mount -t cifs //host/share mountingPoint -o user=guest,password=,vers=3.0

The vers option specifies the SMB protocol version. You can try vers=2.0 or vers=1.0 if vers=3.0 does not work.
Check for any relevant logs in dmesg, it can provide more detailed information about why the mount is failing.
dmesg | grep CIFS

As a temporary workaround, you can use smbclient to access the share:
smbclient //host/share -U guest

That should do it. Good luck!

Ensure that SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support is enabled on the Windows 11 machine. Sometimes, newer versions of Windows have SMB 1.0 disabled by default. This is a terrible recommendation. SMB 1 hasn't been needed in 20 years and is a critical security risk.

That is not the answer, but he is also running windows, most of that OS' code-base is 20+ years old.
I wrote in the answer "vers=3.0".
The extra information is a work-around in case there are clients that require it, it happens in environments with lots of computers. But I agree, maybe I shouldn't mention it.
